# Using command line instructions in VS2010

Tags: c++, command-line, system-calls, visual-studio-2010

I would like to call from a program in VS2010 C++ a windows application using a system call.

How is that possible in Windows? I would like to compress a file using the 7z applicaition. Can I call it from the VS2010 program?

The command is: C:\Program Files\7-Zip>7z a -mx9 -tbzip2 zip1.bz2 History.txt

Thank you

Comment: Yes you can call this from a windows c++ program with the system() function or CreateProcess. If 7z is not in the path you must use the full path.

Comment: Did you [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+execute+command+line)?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
   or
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
   or
3. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687393(v=vs.85).aspx
   or
   call system() function

Comment: It is great that this answer helped, but it could be better if you even just gave "titles" to the links. Check out the [Provide context for links](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) topic.

Comment: Will fix this in my future answers :) Thanks